# D3 multi-line plot is displaying 2 lines not 3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

Ultimately, I am just trying to plot Node.js memory usage over time, in a simple multi-line plot. Maybe there is a package that already does this, but I don't see one. There are 3 components to Node.js/V8 memory usage, `heapUsed`, `heapTotal`, and `rss`, I'd like to plot them over time.

To do a multi-line plot with D3, I am following the example here:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-multi-line-chart-using-d3js--cms-22935

the full code from the example is here:
https://github.com/jay3dec/MultiLineChart_D3/blob/master/index.html

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <link href='http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/justified-nav.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' charset='utf-8'></script>

  <style>

    .axis path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #777;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .axis text {
      font-family: Lato;
      font-size: 13px;
    }

  </style>

</head>

<body>

<div class='container'>

  <div class='jumbotron'>

    <svg id='visualisation' width='1000' height='500'></svg>

    <script>

      var heapTotal = [
        {x: Date.now() - 500, y: 100},
        {x: Date.now(), y: 125},
        {x: Date.now() + 500, y: 150},
      ];

      var heapUsed = [
        {x: Date.now() - 500, y: 110},
        {x: Date.now(), y: 111},
        {x: Date.now() + 500, y: 112},
      ];

      var rss = [
        {x: Date.now() - 500, y: 44},
        {x: Date.now(), y: 44},
        {x: Date.now() + 500, y: 44},
      ];

      const values = heapTotal.concat(heapUsed).concat(rss).reduce(function (prev, curr) {

        console.log('curr => ', curr);

        return {
          xMin: Math.min(prev.xMin, curr.x),
          xMax: Math.max(prev.xMax, curr.x),
          yMin: Math.min(prev.yMin, curr.y),
          yMax: Math.max(prev.yMax, curr.y),
        }

      }, {
        xMin: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
        xMax: -1,
        yMin: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
        yMax: -1
      });

      console.log('values => ', values);

      var vis = d3.select('#visualisation'),
        WIDTH = 1200,
        HEIGHT = 800,
        MARGINS = {
          top: 20,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 20,
          left: 50
        },
        xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([values.xMin, values.xMax]),
        yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([values.yMin, values.yMax]),
        xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale),
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('left');

      vis.append('svg:g')
      .attr('class', 'x axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ')')
      .call(xAxis);

      vis.append('svg:g')
      .attr('class', 'y axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (MARGINS.left) + ',0)')
      .call(yAxis);

      var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function (d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
      })
      .y(function (d) {
        return yScale(d.y);
      })
      .interpolate('basis');

      vis.append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', lineGen(heapUsed))
      .attr('stroke', 'green')
      .attr('stroke-width', 2)
      .attr('fill', 'none');

      vis.append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', lineGen(heapTotal))
      .attr('stroke', 'blue')
      .attr('stroke-width', 2)
      .attr('fill', 'none');

      vis.append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', lineGen(rss))
      .attr('stroke', 'red')
      .attr('stroke-width', 2)
      .attr('fill', 'none');


    </script>
  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

But for some reason, it only plots 2 lines, not 3:

[image]

Anybody have any idea why?

It appears that 3rd line just isn't visible given the dimensions - aka, the y axis does not go down to 44.

Here is screenshot of the values object from the code:

[image]

Comment: note that the data I provided D3 is just bogus sample data to get things working..node.js memory would certainly not be linear like that.

Comment: the first two plots look correct, but it's simply missing the third plot for `rss`.

Comment: Your Y axis doesn't appear (from the screenshot at least) to go down to 44.  What values are you using for the Y domain?

Comment: @TomShanley yes you are correct - for some reason the y-axis is not going down to 44, I didn't really realize that until now. If you run the HTML it will log the values object. I updated the question to show the details.

Comment: Maybe  should be setting range as well as domain

Comment: Yeah there is something wrong with the two xScale/yScale lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your SVG selection (named `vis`) points to this SVG element...

```
<svg id='visualisation' width='1000' height='500'></svg>
```

... which has a height of 500px.

However, your vertical scale (yScale) uses the `HEIGHT` variable, which is `800`.

Therefore, the axis is correct, but it's going *beyond* the lower limit of the SVG (you can clearly see that inspecting the element), as well as your third line, which is being painted, but it's not visible because it currently lies outside the SVG limits.

**Solution**: use the `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` variables to set the height and width of your SVG:

```
vis.attr("width", WIDTH)
    .attr("height", HEIGHT)
```

Alternatively, if the height you want is in fact the inline height of that SVG (that is, `500`), change your `HEIGHT` variable accordingly.

Here is your updated code, now you can see the last line:

```js
var heapTotal = [{
   x: Date.now() - 500,
   y: 100
 }, {
   x: Date.now(),
   y: 125
 }, {
   x: Date.now() + 500,
   y: 150
 }, ];

 var heapUsed = [{
   x: Date.now() - 500,
   y: 110
 }, {
   x: Date.now(),
   y: 111
 }, {
   x: Date.now() + 500,
   y: 112
 }, ];

 var rss = [{
   x: Date.now() - 500,
   y: 44
 }, {
   x: Date.now(),
   y: 44
 }, {
   x: Date.now() + 500,
   y: 44
 }, ];

 const values = heapTotal.concat(heapUsed).concat(rss).reduce(function(prev, curr) {


   return {
     xMin: Math.min(prev.xMin, curr.x),
     xMax: Math.max(prev.xMax, curr.x),
     yMin: Math.min(prev.yMin, curr.y),
     yMax: Math.max(prev.yMax, curr.y),
   }

 }, {
   xMin: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
   xMax: -1,
   yMin: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
   yMax: -1
 });


 var vis = d3.select('#visualisation'),
   WIDTH = 1200,
   HEIGHT = 800,
   MARGINS = {
     top: 20,
     right: 20,
     bottom: 20,
     left: 50
   },
   xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([values.xMin, values.xMax]),
   yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0.95*values.yMin, values.yMax]),
   xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(xScale),
   yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(yScale)
   .orient('left');

 vis.attr("width", WIDTH)
   .attr("height", HEIGHT)

 vis.append('svg:g')
   .attr('class', 'x axis')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ')')
   .call(xAxis);

 vis.append('svg:g')
   .attr('class', 'y axis')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (MARGINS.left) + ',0)')
   .call(yAxis);

 var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d) {
     return xScale(d.x);
   })
   .y(function(d) {
     return yScale(d.y);
   })
   .interpolate('basis');

 vis.append('svg:path')
   .attr('d', lineGen(heapUsed))
   .attr('stroke', 'green')
   .attr('stroke-width', 2)
   .attr('fill', 'none');

 vis.append('svg:path')
   .attr('d', lineGen(heapTotal))
   .attr('stroke', 'blue')
   .attr('stroke-width', 2)
   .attr('fill', 'none');

 vis.append('svg:path')
   .attr('d', lineGen(rss))
   .attr('stroke', 'red')
   .attr('stroke-width', 2)
   .attr('fill', 'none');
```

```css
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg id='visualisation'></svg>
```

PS: I reduced the lower end of your scale a little bit (`0.95*values.yMin`), so the last line doesn't stay on top of the axis.

Comment: thanks! do you have any idea if (and why) I would need to set both range() and domain() for d3.scale.linear()? It seems like I would only need to set range() for x and domain() for y?

Comment: Yes, you have to set **both** range and domain for **both** scales. The scale maps an input domain to an output range. If you don't set any of them, it defaults to `[0, 1]`.

Comment: ughh, your code, works, when I changed mine to scale everything instead of just xMin:

Comment: `xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([values.xMin*.9, values.xMax*1.15]),
        yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([values.yMin*.9, values.yMax*1.15]),`

Comment: it somehow completely barfs when I scale in all 4 ways, not just yMin*.9

Comment: do you have any idea why that would be? Why would it work if I multiply values.yMin*.95, but not work when I multiply all four values by a scalar?

Comment: Well, what you just did is pretty much the default way, which I do all the time. I'm not sure why it didn't work in your case. Please, since this question was already fixed, post a *new* question regarding this multiplication problem, explaining how it *barfs*.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I will probably post that new question tomorrow if I cannot figure it out. If you can look at this related one, that would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408077/y-axis-labels-are-cut-off-on-d3-plot if you can answer it, another 10 pts is yours.