# Y axis labels are cut off on D3 plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this multi-line plot with D3:

[image]

But as you can see, the beginning of the y-axis labels are cut off - anybody know how I can properly display the full label?

And if you have any advice on how to rotate the x-axis labels by 90 degrees, that would help too.

Here is the complete code which generates the plot:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <link href='http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/justified-nav.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' charset='utf-8'></script>

  <style>

    .axis path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #777;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .axis text {
      font-family: Lato;
      font-size: 13px;
    }

  </style>

</head>

<body>

<div class='container'>

  <div class='jumbotron'>

    <svg id='visualisation'></svg>

    <script>

      var heapTotal = JSON.parse('[{"x":1501478175044,"y":18911232},{"x":1501478177048,"y":19959808}]');
      var heapUsed = JSON.parse('[{"x":1501478175044,"y":10492112},{"x":1501478177048,"y":10904080}]');
      var rss = JSON.parse('[{"x":1501478175044,"y":35622912},{"x":1501478177048,"y":36134912}]');

      const values = heapTotal.concat(heapUsed).concat(rss).reduce(function (prev, curr) {

        console.log('curr => ', curr);

        return {
          xMin: Math.min(prev.xMin, curr.x),
          xMax: Math.max(prev.xMax, curr.x),
          yMin: Math.min(prev.yMin, curr.y),
          yMax: Math.max(prev.yMax, curr.y),
        }

      }, {
        xMin: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
        xMax: -1,
        yMin: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
        yMax: -1
      });

      console.log('values => ', values);

      var vis = d3.select('#visualisation'),
        WIDTH = 1200,
        HEIGHT = 800,
        MARGINS = {
          top: 20,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 20,
          left: 50
        },
        xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([values.xMin - 50, values.xMax + 50]),
        yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([values.yMin - 50, values.yMax + 50]),
        xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale),
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('left');

      vis.attr("width", WIDTH)
      .attr("height", HEIGHT);

      vis.append('svg:g')
      .attr('class', 'x axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ')')
      .call(xAxis);

      vis.append('svg:g')
      .attr('class', 'y axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (MARGINS.left) + ',0)')
      .call(yAxis);

      var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function (d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
      })
      .y(function (d) {
        return yScale(d.y);
      })
      .interpolate('basis');

      vis.append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', lineGen(heapUsed))
      .attr('stroke', 'green')
      .attr('stroke-width', 2)
      .attr('fill', 'none');

      vis.append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', lineGen(heapTotal))
      .attr('stroke', 'blue')
      .attr('stroke-width', 2)
      .attr('fill', 'none');

      vis.append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', lineGen(rss))
      .attr('stroke', 'red')
      .attr('stroke-width', 2)
      .attr('fill', 'none');


    </script>
  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: note that I removed some data, there are only 2 data points per line in the example, but otherwise code is identical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One easy `css` way is to give some `padding` to the `svg` element. It will keep the map in better shape.

**METHOD 1:** just change the left margin value in the script:

```
MARGINS = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50 // change this to something larger like 100
  },
```

**Method 2: Using CSS**

```js
var heapTotal = JSON.parse(
  '[{"x":1501478175044,"y":18911232},{"x":1501478177048,"y":19959808}]'
);
var heapUsed = JSON.parse(
  '[{"x":1501478175044,"y":10492112},{"x":1501478177048,"y":10904080}]'
);
var rss = JSON.parse(
  '[{"x":1501478175044,"y":35622912},{"x":1501478177048,"y":36134912}]'
);

const values = heapTotal.concat(heapUsed).concat(rss).reduce(function(
  prev,
  curr
) {
  console.log("curr => ", curr);

  return {
    xMin: Math.min(prev.xMin, curr.x),
    xMax: Math.max(prev.xMax, curr.x),
    yMin: Math.min(prev.yMin, curr.y),
    yMax: Math.max(prev.yMax, curr.y)
  };
}, {
  xMin: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
  xMax: -1,
  yMin: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
  yMax: -1
});

console.log("values => ", values);

var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
  WIDTH = 1200,
  HEIGHT = 800,
  MARGINS = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  },
  xScale = d3.scale
    .linear()
    .range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right])
    .domain([values.xMin - 50, values.xMax + 50]),
  yScale = d3.scale
    .linear()
    .range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom])
    .domain([values.yMin - 50, values.yMax + 50]),
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

vis.attr("width", WIDTH).attr("height", HEIGHT);

vis
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

vis
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + MARGINS.left + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);

var lineGen = d3.svg
  .line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.x);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y);
  })
  .interpolate("basis");

vis
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", lineGen(heapUsed))
  .attr("stroke", "green")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");

vis
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", lineGen(heapTotal))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");

vis
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", lineGen(rss))
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

```css
#visualisation{
  padding: 0px 20px;
}
.axis path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #777;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .axis text {
      font-family: Lato;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id='visualisation'></svg>
```

Comment: thanks, if I use the css technique and add 20px of padding, the x-axis labels disappear, fml

Comment: @AlexanderMills, try the second method also that I mentioned. I think you need a combination of both the margins and CSS.

Comment: @AlexanderMills, also updated the CSS. Check the snippet now.

Comment: thanks that seemed to work, appreciate it! Now I can try to rotate the x-axis labels 90 degrees, and see if I can keep the good format...

Answer (score 1):

The file is set up nicely to make this pretty easy. You can just change the left margin. Something like 75 seems to work to keep you axis labels from clipping.:

```
MARGINS = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 75
},
```

The class `jumbotron` is adding a margin to the whole div, which you might need to change move the chart if this pushes everything over to far to the right.